# how it possible to present alert by tapping button in nib?

Tags: ios, swift, alert, nib

i'm relatively new to programming and swift, I hope you understand that the beginning is sometimes difficult.

i have integrated a login form in a NIB and would like to call up an alert by func if the entry is incorrect. however, the call of present and dismiss an alert are only possible in the view controller. but what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: So my approach would be different to yours. you can comp are the values and if they are incorrect pop up the alert. No need to move to another NIB, until those values are satisfied. Welcome to Stack and the world of Swift :)

Comment: Thank you for your approach. however, the view controller loads a nib in which the test runs. therefore an alert should be loaded in the view controller if the information is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** You can either pass a weak reference of ViewController to which you add this nib as subview and use that to present alert

**Approach 2:** Use protocol/delegate or closure to communicate between nib's view class and view controller and present alert using the delegate method or closure

**Approach 3:** If you dont wanna do any of that, you can always access root view controller and try presenting the alert using root view controller

If you are using `SceneDelegate` then

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first, let sceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? SceneDelegate, let window = sceneDelegate.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "your title", message: "your message", preferredStyle: .alert)
            rootViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

And if you are not using `SceneDelegate`

```
        if let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "abcd", message: "efgh", preferredStyle: .alert)
            rootViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: @Reilaan: Did it work? or you are still facing issue?

Comment: I'm currently testing out which of the options is best to implement. I will definitely give you feedback after successful implementation ;)

Comment: I currently use neither SceneDelegate nor AppDelegate. I'm still too fresh in swift and have yet to learn to understand it. 

I tried to pass it to the ViewController, but the result was that it reloads the entire ViewController and discards changed content

Comment: @reilaan: If you have a working XCode iOS App, you must have AppDelegate or SceneDelegate, Just search `AppDelegate.swift` and `SceneDelegate.swift`, if your development target is above 12 you might have `SceneDelegate.swift` along with `AppDelegate.swift` else you will only have `AppDelegate.swift` I would like to learn a new way to develop iOS application without `AppDelegate` and `SceneDelegate` that you might have invented :P

Comment: I am new to iOS Application I dont know `SceneDelegate` or `AppDelegate` isnt the proper answer, how do you think iOS communicates application lifecycle to app without `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`? How do you think Window loads the root view controller? `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` are fundamental to application your application cant work without them, iOS expects your app to have it, so much so that when you create application using xcode template it default adds app delegate, read the callbacks in both these delegates will help you future to achieve far complicated things

Comment: it would be nice: D
the reality is that i'm learning swift and english at the same time. that is why swift presents me with challenges and misunderstandings arise in my communication, please excuse me for this.